# How does ~/ work?

Tags: command-line, bash, home-directory, sh, dash-shell

In the terminal, one way to reference home is by using `~/`. I don't understand how this works, because the output of `file ~/` is:

```
/home/admin/: directory
```

and just running `~/` results in:

```
-bash: /home/admin/: Is a directory
```

so what's converting `~/` into `/home/admin`?

`~/` also appears to work in `/bin/dash`, so I also know it's not bash specific.

Comment: AFAIK it's a POSIX feature: see for example [Tilde Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_01)

Comment: Check out the bash manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html

Comment: "*and just running ~/*" The very premise of running a directory is flawed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### This is [tilde expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01).

Tilde expansion is required by [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) (see that [first linked page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01)) and appears in all modern [Bourne-style shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Bourne_shell). That includes the popular shells `bash`, `ksh93`, and `zsh`, but also more minimalist shells like `mksh`, `dash`, and `busybox ash`.

In practice, different POSIX-compatible shells sometimes differ in the precise details of tilde expansion, both in the unspecified case that `HOME` would be used but is unset or empty, and to permit `~` notation to be used for other purposes than expanding users' home directories. For example, [tilde expansion in `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Tilde-Expansion) also provides a shorthand for accessing the values of the `PWD` and `OLDPWD` variables, with `~-` and `~+`, respectively.

However, in the typical cases, it works about the same across Bourne-style shells. These are typical cases (but note that this way of *separating* them is not official, it's just my way of presenting the material):

- `~` or `~/` by itself expands to your home directory.
- `~/` followed by more path components expands to a path starting at your home directory.
- `~username` or `~username/` by itself expands to the home directory of the user whose username is `username`.
- `~username/` followed by more path components expands to a path starting at the home directory of the user whose username is `username`.

Comment: It also appears in non-Bourne style shells like tcsh.

Comment: May be also worth noting that username indicates not just actual human but also system users, and may come from database other than just `passwd`.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/423962/85039

Answer (score 5):

### `~` is 'shorthand' for `$HOME`

**`~`** is a 'shorthand' way to write `$HOME` in other words your home directory. It works in shells (e.g. `bash`) and is called 'tilde expansion'.

If you add a trailing slash you imply that you are talking about a directory.

Examples:

```
$ ls -d ~/
/home/sudodus/
$ ls -d ~
/home/sudodus
$ ls -d $HOME
/home/sudodus

$ sudo -i
[sudo] lösenord för sudodus: 
# ls -d ~/
/root/
# ls -d ~
/root
# exit
logout

$ ls xournal.png
xournal.png

$ LANG=C ls xournal.png/
ls: cannot access 'xournal.png/': Not a directory
```